# C++ linker error: Undefined reference - when linking package libtorch and shared objects together

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, shared-libraries

I'm new to CMake and also trying to understand how linking works, or what could cause `libtorch` and `OpenNMTTokenizer.so` not work together. The former is a package with a CMake config, and the latter is a shared library.

If I remove either one of them the binary works fine, but they can't link in the same project. Maybe the headers are missing for `OpenNMTTokenizer.so`, but I'm not sure how to properly add them.

This is the error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/example_shared.dir/src/app.cpp.o: in function `main':
app.cpp:(.text+0x292): undefined reference to `onmt::Tokenizer::joiner_marker'
/usr/bin/ld: app.cpp:(.text+0x2a7): undefined reference to `onmt::Tokenizer::Tokenizer(onmt::Tokenizer::Mode, int, std::string const&, std::string const&, std::string const&, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The program is a simple hello world just to isolate the problem:

```
.
│
├── CMakeLists.txt
│
├── src
│   └── app.cpp
├── include
│   └── app.h.in
│   └── app.h
├── build
```

```
#
#. Project meta
#
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2 FATAL_ERROR)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
project(hello_world)
configure_file(include/app.h.in include/app.h)

#
# Add libraries
#

# 1. Torch
find_package(Torch REQUIRED PATHS /usr/local/libtorch)
# Required flags 
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${TORCH_CXX_FLAGS}")
if (Torch_FOUND)
  list(APPEND LINK_LIBRARIES "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}")
else()
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Cannot find libtorch")
endif()

# 2. OpenNMTTokenizer
find_library(OpenNMTTokenizer lib/libOpenNMTTokenizer.so)
if (OpenNMTTokenizer)
  add_library(OpenNMTTokenizer SHARED IMPORTED lib/libOpenNMTTokenizer.so)
  set_target_properties(OpenNMTTokenizer
    PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION /usr/local/lib/libOpenNMTTokenizer.so
    LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
  list(APPEND LINK_LIBRARIES OpenNMTTokenizer "${OpenNMTTokenizer_LIBRARIES}")
else()
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Cannot find OpenNMTTokenizer")
endif()

#
# Add the executable
#
add_executable("${PROJECT_NAME}" src/app.cpp)
set_property(TARGET "${PROJECT_NAME}" PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)
target_link_libraries("${PROJECT_NAME}" "${LINK_LIBRARIES}")

target_include_directories("${PROJECT_NAME}" PUBLIC
  "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include"
  "${TORCH_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

set_target_properties("${PROJECT_NAME}"
  PROPERTIES
  ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/../lib"
  LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/../lib"
  RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/../bin"
)
```

And this is the source `src/app.cpp`

```
#include "app.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <torch/torch.h>
#include <torch/script.h>
#include <onmt/Tokenizer.h>

using namespace onmt;

int main(){
  torch::Tensor tensor = torch::eye(3);
  std::cout << tensor << std::endl;

  // It doesn't work if torch is linked
  Tokenizer tokenizer(Tokenizer::Mode::Conservative, Tokenizer::Flags::JoinerAnnotate);

  return 0;
}
```

**Complete build output**

```
/usr/local/bin/cmake -S/home/inez/Projects/cmake_hello_world -B/home/inez/Projects/cmake_hello_world/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/inez/Projects/cmake_hello_world/build/CMakeFiles /home/inez/Projects/cmake_hello_world/build//CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make  -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/inez/Projects/cmake_hello_world/build'
make  -f CMakeFiles/hello_world.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/hello_world.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/inez/Projects/cmake_hello_world/build'
cd /home/inez/Projects/cmake_hello_world/build && /usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/inez/Projects/cmake_hello_world /home/inez/Projects/cmake_hello_world /home/inez/Projects/cmake_hello_world/build /home/inez/Projects/cmake_hello_world/build /home/inez/Projects/cmake_hello_world/build/CMakeFiles/hello_world.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
Dependencies file "CMakeFiles/hello_world.dir/src/app.cpp.o.d" is newer than depends file "/home/inez/Projects/cmake_hello_world/build/CMakeFiles/hello_world.dir/compiler_depend.internal".
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target hello_world
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/inez/Projects/cmake_hello_world/build'
make  -f CMakeFiles/hello_world.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/hello_world.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/inez/Projects/cmake_hello_world/build'
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable ../bin/hello_world
/usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/hello_world.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++  -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -rdynamic CMakeFiles/hello_world.dir/src/app.cpp.o -o ../bin/hello_world  -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/libtorch/lib:/usr/local/cuda-11.2/lib64/stubs:/usr/local/cuda-11.2/lib64:/usr/local/lib /usr/local/libtorch/lib/libtorch.so /usr/local/libtorch/lib/libc10.so /usr/local/libtorch/lib/libkineto.a /usr/local/cuda-11.2/lib64/stubs/libcuda.so /usr/local/cuda-11.2/lib64/libnvrtc.so -lnvToolsExt /usr/local/cuda-11.2/lib64/libcudart.so /usr/local/libtorch/lib/libc10_cuda.so /usr/local/lib/libOpenNMTTokenizer.so -Wl,--no-as-needed,"/usr/local/libtorch/lib/libtorch_cuda.so" -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-as-needed,"/usr/local/libtorch/lib/libtorch_cuda_cpp.so" -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-as-needed,"/usr/local/libtorch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so" -Wl,--as-needed -lpthread /usr/local/libtorch/lib/libc10_cuda.so /usr/local/libtorch/lib/libc10.so /usr/local/cuda-11.2/lib64/libcufft.so /usr/local/cuda-11.2/lib64/libcurand.so /usr/local/cuda-11.2/lib64/libcublas.so /usr/local/cuda-11.2/lib64/libcudnn.so -Wl,--no-as-needed,"/usr/local/libtorch/lib/libtorch_cuda_cu.so" -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-as-needed,"/usr/local/libtorch/lib/libtorch.so" -Wl,--as-needed -lnvToolsExt /usr/local/cuda-11.2/lib64/libcudart.so 
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/hello_world.dir/src/app.cpp.o: in function `main':
app.cpp:(.text+0x292): undefined reference to `onmt::Tokenizer::joiner_marker'
/usr/bin/ld: app.cpp:(.text+0x2a7): undefined reference to `onmt::Tokenizer::Tokenizer(onmt::Tokenizer::Mode, int, std::string const&, std::string const&, std::string const&, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/hello_world.dir/build.make:114: ../bin/hello_world] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/inez/Projects/cmake_hello_world/build'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/hello_world.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/inez/Projects/cmake_hello_world/build'
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

**Torch has a TorchConfig.make**

```
# Finds the Torch library
#
# This will define the following variables:
#
#   TORCH_FOUND        -- True if the system has the Torch library
#   TORCH_INCLUDE_DIRS -- The include directories for torch
#   TORCH_LIBRARIES    -- Libraries to link against
#   TORCH_CXX_FLAGS    -- Additional (required) compiler flags
```

Linked libraries from `LINK_LIBRARIES`

```
LINK_LIBRARIES=torchtorch_library/usr/local/libtorch/lib/libc10.so/usr/local/libtorch/lib/libkineto.a/usr/local/cuda-11.2/lib64/stubs/libcuda.so/usr/local/cuda-11.2/lib64/libnvrtc.so/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvToolsExt.so/usr/local/cuda-11.2/lib64/libcudart.so/usr/local/libtorch/lib/libc10_cuda.soOpenNMTTokenizer
```

### See the answer below

The libraries were linked to different standard libraries. As suggested by *@botje*, the value for `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` didn't match.

I recompiled `OpenNMTTokenizer` with this line, then the main project compiled without errors:

```
add_compile_definitions(_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0)
```

**From libstdc++**

> If you get linker errors about undefined references to symbols that involve types in the std::__cxx11 namespace or the tag [abi:cxx11] then it probably indicates that you are trying to link together object files that were compiled with different values for the _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI macro.

> This commonly happens when linking to a third-party library that was
> compiled with an older version of GCC. If the third-party library
> cannot be rebuilt with the new ABI then you will need to recompile
> your code with the old ABI.

[Read more at gnu.org](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html)

Comment: Can you show the build output if you run `make VERBOSE=1` ? That will tell us if the opennmt library is being linked at all.

Comment: Also, what is the final contents of the `LINK_LIBRARIES` variable?

Comment: I don't know how to debug it, but it should have `OpenNMTTokenizer`, and predefined `TORCH_LIBRARIES`

Comment: Please inspect the contents with something like `message( LINK_LIBRARIES is ${LINK_LIBRARIES})`

Comment: That -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 is suspicious. Can you check with `nm -C /usr/local/lib/libOpenNMTTokenizer.so` if the needed symbol is present in that library and if has the CXX11 ABI tag or not?

Comment: It think it does
```U std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::compare(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const@@GLIBCXX_3.4.21
```

Comment: The `std::__cxx11` part means that that library is using the [CXX11 ABI](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html), while you explicitly disable that while compiliing your app.cpp. All components of your application (app, torch, openNMTT) need to agree on which ABI to use. I think you will have to either recompile Torch *with* the CXX11 ABI, or opennmt *without* the CXX11 ABI.

Comment: Thank you! I compiled the OpenNMTTokenizer again with `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` and it worked! Please add this as an answer for reference

Comment: Will do. Note that the CXX11 ABI is the default going forward and you should strive for the opposite situation.

Comment: Please do not add "solution" section to your question, add an answer instead (you can answer your own question and accept the answer, this is encouraged).

Comment: @Botje I tried it first but Torch didn't compile, and the other compiled without a problem. I'll try again and keep that in mind, thanks!

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Understood. I moved the section below instead of removing it completely, since it has an example and references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, it turns out that one of the components (OpenNMTTokenizer) was compiled **WITH** the CXX11 ABI, and the other two (Torch and app.cpp) were not. This caused a mismatch in symbol names.

The immediate fix was to recompile OpenNMTTokenizer without the CXX11 ABI, although the proper fix is to compile everything with the CXX11 ABI. This would mean recompiling Torch.